# Sublime Text 2 - Error but not in IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sublimetext2

I'm trying to use Sublime text and I have changed my compiling settings to also display the output form the java program. However, I can not run it in Sublime Text 2, while IntelliJ displays it fine, as does DrJava and Eclipse.

My error is:

> ```
> -----------OUTPUT-----------
> This program will calculate the average for the given number of student's marks
> How many students are in the class?
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>   at Unit4ClassAverage.main(Unit4ClassAverage.java:33)
> [Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
> ```

The block of code responsible for this, I'm guessing is:

```
System.out.println("This program will calculate the average for the given number of student's marks");
            System.out.println("How many students are in the class?");
            strInput = br.readLine();
            intStudents = Integer.parseInt(strInput);
```

My JavaC.sublime-build file looks as follows:

```
{
    "cmd": ["runJava.bat", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

and my runJava.bat file looks as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd %~dp1
ECHO Compiling %~nx1.......
IF EXIST %~n1.class (
DEL %~n1.class
)
javac %~nx1
IF EXIST %~n1.class (
ECHO -----------OUTPUT-----------
java %~n1
)
```

which is located in my "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin" folder.

Any help would be appreciated!
The entire program can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/d5QDqMbJ

Comment: Which class type is the variable `br`? `strInput` is not a string representing an integer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis hi, that would be here
`code //Stream and Buffered readers to take user input
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr); `
the user is expected to put in a number for that part of the program and a catch is set up for (IOException)

Answer (score 0):

Late response but in case anyone is wondering, sublime hasn't imported the utils that you requested in this case. It's problems with the running of the code not of its content.